# SQL Server Deadlocks (SQL Server 2000)

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000, database-deadlocks

I have one customer experiencing 5+ deadlocks per day.  170+ other customers don't get any deadlocks at all.  I've implemented deadlock tracing and can see the select/update/insert deadlocks occurring.  I implemented a with (rowlock) hint and this sorted the initial deadlock out.  However, the thing still deadlocks further on down the line.

I've discovered the customer is running custom SQL which has been causing some of the problems, but not all of them.

My question really is does anyone know whether upgrading the customer from sql server 2000 to sql server 2008 will likely fix the issue?

Thanks,

Col.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on why they are getting the deadlocks at the moment. Without investigation of the cause it is impossible to say.

A couple of advantages that SQL 2005/2008 do have in this area over SQL2000+ is the introduction of snapshot isolation that can remove some deadlock possibilities and better monitoring options to get to the bottom of why a deadlock is occurring.

Comment: I suppose we will get a nice graph in 2008.  That probably won't appease the customer though - I just want the problem to go away!!!!!!    I think I'll advise it may sort the problem out - together with archiving some of the million records on this table.

Answer (score 1):

i don't think that there will be any differences between using sql 2000 or 2008. 
Actually you can solve any deadlock just reasoning on the causes which created them

Comment: I get what you're saying, but this is 1 customer out of 170+ customers getting deadlocks where other customers don't.

Comment: Probably because of his custom SQL. Old rule that mostly applies n these scenarios: custom SQL = no support, but pay us for consulting.